# Как выборать часовой пояс при переводе UNIX время в обычную дату?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, время, datetime

Допустим есть время: `1615813679`.

Надо вывести время в виде даты:

```
print( f" {time.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1615813679))}" )
```

Но такой способ выводит в моем часовом поясе, а хотелось бы выводить в каком-то определенном, например, `+3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT, timezone, timedelta, time

unix_ts = 1615813679

tz = timezone(+timedelta(hours=3))

res = DT.fromtimestamp(unix_ts, tz)

print(f"{res:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z}")
```

вывод:

```
15-03-2021 16:07:59 UTC+03:00
```

Comment: благодарю, то что надо